# Odoo with Google App Engine NDB | Porting from postgresql to NDB

Tags: postgresql, google-app-engine, odoo, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am planning to port **Odoo** to **Google App Engine** Web application. As I came to know that **Odoo** uses **postgresql**., Is it possible to port that database connections, queries and all **from Postgresql** db to **NDB** so that I can run it on Google App Engine ?

Comment: Trying to port oodo to the data store would be an incredibly massive exercise, and probably not possible.  If you want to do something like this maybe cloud sql would be possible rather than the datastore. But even then I doubt it.  This question is not really appropriate for SO, as it is too broad.

Comment: @TimHoffman, Expected you here. Sorry, the one who gave us the project don't want to use cloud sql. He wants to use ndb only. With regards to my best knowledge, I expected it as not so easy one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be a big job ;-) I think the only way to approach such an exercise is see how you could re-implement odoo ORM engine (custom to odoo), and asses that effort.

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/openerp/models.py

It is an explicit homegrown orm, that emboddies things like relations/constraints grouping, etc... many of which have no analog in the datastore.

So the the effort involved would become quite huge.

Higher level abstractions in odoo will depend on model methods of the orm like

```
 def read_group(self, cr, uid, domain, fields, groupby, offset=0, limit=None, context=None, orderby=False, lazy=True):
    """
    Get the list of records in list view grouped by the given ``groupby`` fields
    :param cr: database cursor
    :param uid: current user id
    :param domain: list specifying search criteria [['field_name', 'operator', 'value'], ...]
    :param list fields: list of fields present in the list view specified on the object
    :param list groupby: list of groupby descriptions by which the records will be grouped.  
            A groupby description is either a field (then it will be grouped by that field)
            or a string 'field:groupby_function'.  Right now, the only functions supported
            are 'day', 'week', 'month', 'quarter' or 'year', and they only make sense for 
            date/datetime fields.

 ....
```

Clearly much of this is irrelevant or not doable in the datastore, directly (groupby) but could be done in memory - hence in your own ORM replacement.

In the ORM you see a lot of counting going on (hmm that doesn't work well in datastore).

Also Odoo will depend on the locking/consistancy model of an RDBMS which is not the same as the datastores eventual consistancy.  So there is a fundamental approach to be considered.  If you create lots of ancestors keys to help with consistency, you may find a lot of contention is created.  So then you may need some other locking mechanisms, may be CAS in memcache.

So you then might have to look for some higher layer of abstraction in odoo to port your replacement ORM that maps to the datastore. My guess is there isn't a uniform higher level, but I haven't looked ;-)

I haven't looked up higher yet ;-)

There do appear to be models of the odoo data structures and relationships which could mean you could possibly find a higher abstraction layer and auto generate a set of classes representing all of the application data entities from a model/uml or existing code (reverse engineer).  But none of that then deals with any code that may use sql, directly, reporting requirements etc... all of which become harder again, so maybe you need a hybrid model of datastore and big query, and search apps.

I would get someone familiar with the datastore, and look closely at the Odoo ORM and datamodel, and do a feasability study, and proof of concept of core areas to asses if it's doable, and if it could actually work.

Good luck ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation ;-)